# Why working with an open ID?

Tags: openid, abstract

What's the main advantage working with open ID?

Answer (score 6):

You let the user use the same account for many online services; easier for the user to maintain login/password in one place instead of *n* places. Also, you don't need to bother as much about protecting the users' passwords in a secure manner since you, well, don't store them.

Comment: In particular, a small site can get users to sign up without having to ask them to remember yet another set of authentication credentials, since they've probably already got a Google/Yahoo/whatever account that can be used for OpenID.

Answer (score 3):

[Federated identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity).

Comment: That Wikipedia article is seriously jargon-filled and impenetrable.

Comment: @aem Well, you shouldn't just read Wikipedia only, it's a starting point for most of things. You should also read the "See also" and "References" links (hence the names). People like you are making Wikipedia look bad in academic communities by copying and pasting whatever Wikipedia has to offer, and not even looking how it come to such conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

One account for many pages. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

It's good for the user:

- Fewer accounts to manage and passwords to maintain
- Log in once (to the Provider) on a computer, then log into all OpenID relying party web sites very easily without having to re-login, whether you're new to a web site or a returning visitor.

It's good for the web site to be an OpenID relying party:

- Lower the barrier to entry for new visitors to become members since OpenIDs are easier to login with than username/password, and users don't think "oh no, not another password to remember (or reuse)".
- Never worry about "I forgot my password" UI to maintain.
- Allow users to secure their login using InfoCard, X.509 certs, mere passwords, or whatever they want, but your site only has to support one login: OpenID

Answer (score 0):

OpedID is a seriously good idea and I wish more people would use it. Especially forums. 90% of the time I need to sign up somewhere it's to post on some forum. Have you ever browsed over a forum and have this happen to you:

- find interesting thread that you would like to comment on
- click on register
- fill in username, email, email again, password, password again and anything else they want
- it tells me that username is already taken
- I abandon register process and try to log in because maybe I already registered here a long time ago and just forgot?
- my username is recognized but I can't remember the correct password
- go back to register page
- fill in username, email, email again, password, password again and anything else they want
- click submit and wait for the confirmation email is sent
- click activation link in email
- enter username/password after "you account has been activated" screen

...all to make on post on some forum I'm probably never visit again. With openID, it's just:

- enter nbv4.openid.com into textbox
- click on "Accept", or if I already signed up there, it just logs me in.

So easy and so convenient. It sucks that there are a lot of developers who are afraid to go all out with it because they are afraid of joe schmoe users getting confused. As long as you have a nice interface set up (such as the one SO uses), you'll be fine. The site I administer has over 500 users and about 80% are signed up with either a yahoo or gmail email anyways, so most of the time *thats* not going to be a problem either.